# Visual Studio using local path when debugging pages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I debug a page of my Silverlight project in VS2010 it sends the browser to `file:///C:/Users/Chris/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Growing/Growing/Bin/Debug` rather than `http://localhost/`. Does anyone know what happened with this? I don't remember changing any kind of settings for that and have no idea where to change it back.

Comment: Sorry.. Silverlight navigation project. It has a solution with 2 projects, one for silverlight and one for WCF services.  When I click the run button it shows the testpage absolute local path (file:///C:/Users/Chris/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/Growing/Growing/Bin/Debug/GrowingTestPage.html#/Receiving).  When I started the project it used localhost.  It's causing errors when I use relative paths, so I have to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the settings in your Web.csproj file.  If you open it in notepad (or unload it within the solution and right click, edit...), you should be able to see VisualStudio settings.  My guess is that you may need to update those settings.

Here are the settings for one of my SL projects that runs from the localhost.

```
<VisualStudio>
  <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
    <WebProjectProperties>
      <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
      <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
      <DevelopmentServerPort>52878</DevelopmentServerPort>
      <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
      <IISUrl>http://localhost/ExternalWeb</IISUrl>       <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
      <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
      <CustomServerUrl>
      </CustomServerUrl>
      <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
    </WebProjectProperties>
  </FlavorProperties>
</VisualStudio>
```

Comment: I changed the IISUrl (which was blank) to http://localhost/ and it will let me use localhost.  It still won't start with the webserver path, but at least I can enter it manually and do my debug work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there was a web project created for you to host the Silverlight app, is this correct? If so, it's possible you accidentally set the Silverlight project as the startup project rather than the Web project. If you are running it out of IIS you should be able to navigate to it with your browser and see your application. Otherwise the built in web server in VS should launch.