# Visual Studio to always open web site instead of editor's web page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, razor

When I edit .aspx or .cshtml file in the Visual Studio and press Ctrl-F5 (run), it runs the current file in the browser. How do I make it to avoid this and always open the app's site URL instead?

Comment: Try these two answers: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473598/visual-studio-using-local-path-when-debugging-pages/5473973#5473973](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473598/visual-studio-using-local-path-when-debugging-pages/5473973#5473973)

Comment: VS doesn't open local file. It opens page relative to the site, i.e. localhost:1234/Views/Home/Index.cshtml instead of always just localhost:1234, when I edit Index.cshtml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click on your web project, pick properties, go to the 'web' tab, and under 'start action', select 'start URL' and fill in the URL you want to use.

Comment: Silly me, I did not actually have the site URL being set. I was sure it was set.